# html table structure

Tags: html, html-table

I'm very new to html,
and I'm trying to do this:

Is it possible to build a table as follow:
say on size 500X500px.
with a center square size 200X200.
and 4 rectangles around this square (2 will be 200X300, the others300X200 )?
I tried to do so but I'm not sure its even possible.

Comment: http://www.quackit.com/html/html_table_generator.cfm

Comment: if all rectangles are of fixed sizes, then simply absolute position the div however you want them without using table, at least a CSS powered div would be cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" height="150px;"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" width="150px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" width="150px;"></td>
      <td width="200px;" height="200px"></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"   height="150px;"></td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
```

http://jsbin.com/inahaz

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use DIVs:

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ofaqor/3/edit)*

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  
  <div class="box box_vert">1</div>
  <div class="box box_horiz">2</div>
     
  <div class="box center">c</div> 
  
  <div class="box box_vert" style="float:right;">3</div>
  <div class="box box_horiz">4</div> 
  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #wrapper{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px auto;
    background:black;
  }
  .box{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
  }
  .box_horiz{
    width:400px;
  }
  .box_vert{
    height:400px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one
write below code in between style tags 
    table{width:400px;height:400px;}
    td{width:200px;height:200px;}

Comment: but what about the other rectangles?